# Something wrong with apt-get in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, apt, updates

When I try to run apt update I get a such problem:

```
Ign archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Ign archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease                           
Ign archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports InRelease                         
Ign archive.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease                          
Err archive.ubuntu.com wily Release.gpg                                 
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates Release.gpg                         
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports Release.gpg                       
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com wily-security Release.gpg                        
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]
```

I'm tried to figure out what's wrong, but I didn't find an answer.
P.S. I don't use a proxy.

Comment: Did you use that computer to post this question?

Comment: Yes I'm using my laptop.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `apt` is trying to connect with IPv6, which is strange.

Comment: See if you can disable that in Settings.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Well, I don't have Ubuntu booted right now, so I can't give exact instructions, but open Settings/Preferences, go to Network, click the active network connection, click (I think) the Options... button in the lower right and look around in there.

Comment: Is that it? http://i.imgur.com/K0Qc1OT.jpg

Comment: Hmm, no it isn't. Give me a screenshot of Settings>Network.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HupAygX.jpg are you talking about it?

Comment: Ah. Yes. OK, click the little blue arrow next to the WiFi network you are connected to and send another screenshot.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/29MKOAV.jpg

Comment: Click Settings... and send another screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

To disable IPv6 support under Ubuntu, edit the following file: `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1  
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1  
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

Adding these lines will disable IPv6 support (in loopback), a default for all etginterfaces available. You will need to reboot the network interfaces:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Also, selecting "ignore" under ipv6 settings on my connection's settings, fixed my problem.